# Fathom. Is it a commonly used verb?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I have come across the word FATHOM. Is it a commonly used verb in the AmE? Meaning to think, understand smth. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, yankees are still stuck to their Imperial/US Customary system of measurements, so fathoms all around.

Comment: Also commonly used here in the UK, due to some of us old codgers still having imperial in our minds despite metric addition.

Comment: Possible usage: "*I cannot fathom how people still use the fathom as unit!*"

Comment: In America, we do not understand smth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fathom), **fathom** is in the top 30% of popular English words. This probably includes both major meanings of the word:

> **Definition of fathom**
>   1 : a unit of length equal to six feet (1.83 meters) used especially for measuring the depth of water —sometimes used in the singular when qualified by a number five fathom deep
>   2 : comprehension
>   the themes display a newer fathom than the technical modernism of the composer's earlier works —Newsweek
>
> [merriam webster]

Anecdotally, as a non-native speaker I am quite familiar with the word and guess that it is fairly common in its second definition of "comprehension".

Edit: The most common usage, as noted by Henry, is probably as verb form:

> 2 : to penetrate and come to understand. *couldn't fathom the problem*

There's also the related adjective *fathomable*.

Comment: I suspect your definition 2 is more commonly used as a verb than as a noun (while for definition 1, a noun usage is more common)

Comment: @Henry True! I'll add some more on that to my answer.